# Audit question upvote not recorded

Tags: bug, review-audits, voting

When a high-quality audit question is presented in VLQ queue, upvoting the question makes you pass the audit. However, the upvote itself is not recorded. Is this by design or a bug?

If this is by design, what is the rationale? My understanding is that users are always encouraged to vote (there are several badges, some sites even offer [rep prizes](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/earn-the-electorate-badge-in-january-2016-and-get) to active voters). Yet in this situation a perfectly valid vote is discarded.

Comment: Indeed a dupe, sorry. I wish the original question had an answer though.

Comment: I suspect the reason has something to do with the possible processing of audits. I believe that, at least in some queues, the contents or presentation of the post may be altered for the purposes of generating an audit, so the fear is that you may not really be basing your decision to vote on the *actual* post. I'm not sure if that's true in the VLQ queue, but all queues probably use the same code base. Again, just guessing here. If you're lucky, you'll attract the attention of someone that knows more about the review queues than I.

Comment: @CodyGray I know the audit question may be stripped of all comments and votes (which are not supposed to have an influence on my vote), but I don't know anything about *the content* being altered for audit purposes. Do you have a source for this?